Fuse.js demo produces unexpected results
Following the contribution guidelines for Fuse.js, I'm posting this here, mostly for the devs working on Fuse.
I am evaluating client-side search tools, and I tried the demo for Fuse, but it's producing results I didn't expect. I don't know if it's a "bug", or just expected behavior, but it was not what I expected.
The demo has a list of elements, the third element (from the top) looks like this:
  {
    "title": "HTML5",
    "author": {
      "firstName": "Remy",
      "lastName": "Sharp"
    }
  },

The text "Remy" appears only in this one element.
If you enter "remy" as a search term, you get the following results:
[
  {
    "item": {
      "title": "HTML5",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "Remy",
        "lastName": "Sharp"
      }
    },
    "refIndex": 2
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "title": "The Preservationist",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Maine"
      }
    },
    "refIndex": 20
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "title": "Angels & Demons",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "Dan",
        "lastName": "Brown"
      }
    },
    "refIndex": 7
  }
]

The search results correctly retrieve (and rank) the element with "firstName": "Remy", but I can't figure out why the other two results are there. There doesn't seem to be anything in the indexed data for these other results that contain the work "remy".
I think I expected just one result.

The default threshold for the fuzzy-search is 0.6. If you only expected exact matches you can set this to 0.
if you search for "Remy" the "Preservationist" and "Demons" seem to match using 0.6.
